# How to compress PNG image with S3TC/DXT algorithm in python?

Tags: python, opengl, image-processing, dxt

I try to find way for compressing images(PNG as an example) with any S3TC/DXT algorithm using python libraries.

As I can see in [Pillow(PIL)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#fully-supported-formats) library DDS format in `Read-only formats` section. Therefore Pillow can't be used for this purpose.
Searching in google didn't give positive results.

#### Question:

Is it possible to do with python?
Could someone please provide link to libraries with such functional?(which is checked on practice)
**DDS format is not mandatory for my case. I need only compressed file.**

#### PS:

It's required for creating textures for future use.
Library should support different [algorithms of compression.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Compressed_formats)

Comment: Do you mean you want to save an image in Microsoft Direct Draw Surface 1/5 format with the `.dds` extension?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I need to have ability chose algorithm for compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Python [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.2/index.html). Here I create a pseudo image with a magenta-yellow gradient and save as `DDS`:

```
from wand.image import Image
with Image(width=200, height=80, pseudo='gradient:magenta-yellow') as img: 
   img.save(filename='result.dds')
```

[image]

Or, if you want to load a PNG file and save as DDS:

```
with Image(filename='input.png') as img: 
   img.save(filename='result.dds')
```

Comment: It's just saving in other extention. I've looked at `Wand` and didn't find ability to chose compress algorithm: like DXT1-5, etc. https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Compressed_formats

Comment: If I use the above code and save as TIFF, I can add in an extra line before `img.save()` that sets `img.compression='lzw'` or `img.compression='zip'` and it honours that. If I set `img.compression='dxt5'` it does not honour it... maybe Eric will know @emcconville

Comment: yeap, http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.2/wand/image.html?highlight=compression it's really supported, and looks like even can save in dds format with compression. BTW, offtop: .dds files could be used in personal projects? I mean is it legal format? :) (I know it could sound stupid)